# Can we use an impossible condition as a premise in a sound argument?

Tags: deduction

This is going to appear a bit of a mess

### Can we use a syllogism with an impossible condition as a premise in a sound argument?

I am trying to reconstruct an argument. My interlocutor assumes you cannot buy true love from a prostitute, and deduces that you cannot buy true love. I think that they need another premise, and can think of three possible ones

1. Everyone is a prostitute.
2. Love is only bought from prostitutes.
3. True love is only bought from prostitutes.

Both 1 and 2 means everyone who sells their love is a prostitute, which they wouldn't agree with me they meant (incidentally, I just don't know what prostitution has got to do with it so think they can't make the inference they want to). So my question is whether they could use 3 as a premise in their argument.

Or whether, because it states something with impossible condition (the conclusion states that it is impossible to buy true love) it is junk and cannot be used as a premise.

---

1. If P then cannot B a L that is T
2. If B a L that is T then P
3. CONCLUSION: cannot B a L that is T

Comment: A *valid* argument may have an "impossible" assumption, meaning a contradictory assumption, i.e. one that is **always** false. In this case, every statement is a conclusion. See [Ex falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)

Comment: But be aware about the difference between a "false" statement: "Everyone is a prostitute" and a contradictory one (this is a "formal" feature): "Everyone is a prostitute and is not a prostitute".

Comment: yeah @MauroALLEGRANZA if I had to talk about 'prostitution' I would prefer 2 over 1 because I'm skeptical of most universal "intuitions" in the social sciences.

Comment: What I mean is that **IF** you want to check the formal validity of an argument, you have to rewrite it in formal setting... 1) has logical form: "every x is P" (which is **not** always true).

Comment: See [Soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness): "In deductive reasoning, a *sound* argument is an argument that is valid and all of its premises are true (and as a consequence its conclusion is true as well)." Do you think that an "impossible" premise is true?

Comment: No, as Mauro says, a sound argument is normally defined as a valid argument with true premises, so if a premise is impossible then the argument would not be sound.

Comment: There is one vote (not mine) to close this question. While I think the question could be more clearly formulated, and the formalisation at the end much improved, I am inclined to leave the question open because of the value of the comments.

Comment: @user56815: Could you clarify what you mean when describing an argument as "sound"? This term has a specific technical meaning in deductive logic -- i.e. in deductive logic an argument is said to be *"sound"* iff it is a deductively *valid* argument with *no false premises*. *If* that is what you mean, then the answer is straightforward: no sound argument can have an impossible premise, because all impossible premises are false premises, and sound arguments can't have false premises. On the other hand, if you mean something else by "sound," then the answer will depend on what you mean by it...

Answer (score 1):

First, any proposition--any statement that can be assigned a definite truth-value, either true or false--can be a premise in an argument. Or the conclusion, for that matter. The argument may or may not be valid--the conclusion may or may not follow from the premises--and even if it's valid, the argument may or may not be sound--to be sound is to be valid *and* to have all true premises. But any argument can be created from any propositions.

Second, without using quantification, I think you're aiming at this:

1. If S is a prostitute, then true love cannot be bought from S;
2. If S is not a prostitute, then true love cannot be bought from S;
3. Therefore, whether S is or is not a prostitute, true love cannot be bought from S.

Third, with quantification, I think the argument would look like this:

1. For any x, if x is a prostitute, then true love cannot be bought from x;
2. For any y, if y is not a prostitute, then true love cannot be bought from y;
3. Therefore, for any z, true love cannot be bought from z.

(I will point out that as all three are universally quantified, I could have used the same letter in all three had I so chosen.)

Comment: So is your answer to the edited question "yes it can"? If so, I suppose you are right in your reconstruction, though I don't see it as a helpful argument, if only because being unable to buy true love from someone who's not a prostitute is unstated, yet seems to be doing more work. Surely we are more likely to think true love cannot be bought from prostitutes than someone who doesn't make a living from selling love - at least if we agree that true love cannot be bought?

Comment: "Yes it can" is my answer-- but remember, if you disagree with one of the premises, then the argument provides no reason for you to accept its conclusion. If you disagree with the premise that one cannot buy true love from a non-prostitute, then you need not agree with the conclusion, either. However, if what you are asking is whether or not an impossible premise can be a premise in a sound argument, then the answer is "No, it can't, for the simple reason that all of the premises in a sound argument are true."

Comment: huh? sorry I am not willing to work out what you might mean there. my edited question reads "Can we use an impossible condition as a premise in a sound argument?"

Comment: if you mean that the falseness of my love for the prostitute makes yours true, well I think that you don't take things seriously enough. even if we grant that authenticity ('truth') is relative to a culture (which may not be radical enough), in this instances visitors to a brothel, I believe you misunderstand just how far reaching it is to claim that the best we've got is "true". you may take most, if not all, skepticism out with that

Comment: it seems rushed. suppose we have five significant arguments for or against the existence of God, and our best argument is fairly convincing. does that alone mean we know God exists? even if we take them all together as a fairly convincing set of arguments for God's existence, can we infer knowledge? even if we shift the burden of proof, it sure as hell isn't conclusive that you truly love the prostitute.

Comment: so your 'true love' (qua 'truest love') is - I think - not conclusively shown to be true love, is not known to be true love, and is "true love" only relative not to how *false* every other love for the prostitute is (think: it doesn't matter that others have failed), but in fact how close they are to truth (the more claims there are the less likely yours is). unless I suppose she loves others?

Comment: anon: As to your first comment after my last comment: Once you change the question to "Can we use an impossible condition as a premise in a sound argument," the answer becomes "No, because a sound argument has premises that are all true but an impossible condition cannot be true." As to the rest, first, I was not using the word "truth" in any but an objective way. The reason the answer to the question "Can we use an impossible condition as a premise in an argument" was "Yes" was *only* that an argument need not be sound in order to be an argument. (I see: there's a character limit. Cont'd)

Comment: No, five unsound arguments do not provide evidence of anything. I am speaking here of deductive arguments, as I thought we were doing throughout. However, an individual might not know whether or not a particular premise is true and might be able to do no better than assign it an epistemic likelihood, which, if the argument is valid, he might then transfer to the conclusion when evaluating how strongly the argument does or does not support the conclusion. A sufficiently high degree of epistemic likelihood might strongly justify a claim of knowledge without justifying a claim of certainty.

Comment: As to the OP's distinction between love and true love, I have ignored it in favor of addressing the logic involved if one simply uses the two terms equivalently throughout. If  you intend there to be a relevant distinction between the meanings of "love" and of "true love," you will have to tell us what it is.

Comment: ah ok sorry miscommunication then.